# Automatic forecasting in R discrepancy

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, exponential-smoothing

I am new to time series forecasting and I am trying to understand automatic forecasting algorithm in the forecast package in R.

I read http://www.jstatsoft.org/v27/i03 this paper and I tried to run:

```
forecast(t_series_NOT_MODEL)
```

However, the results are different from:

```
e = ets(t_series_NOT_MODEL)
forecast(e)
```

Apparently, according to the paper:

> There is also a method for a ts object. If a time series object is passed as the first argument to
>   forecast(), the function will produce forecasts based on the exponential smoothing algorithm
>   of Section 2.

Which means that forecast and ets output should be same, or am I make a mistake?
forecast() outputs a model with name -> STL + ETS(A,N,N) 
whereas, ets() outputs a model with name -> ETS(A,N,N)

**EDIT :**

> If model=NULL,the function forecast.ts makes forecasts using ets
>   models (if the data are non-seasonal or the seasonal period is 12 or
>   less) or stlf (if the seasonal period is 13 or more).

So does that mean that since my model is STL + ETS, that means that my data is seasonal? Also if that is the case why does ETS decide on (A,N,N) rather than (A,N,A) or (A,N,M) ?

Answer (score 2):

You should read the documentation for that specific function by:

```
library(forecast)
?forecast
```

The forecast function in the R forecast package will return an ETS model if the frequency is <13 (seasonal or non-seasonal), otherwise it will apply a non-seasonal forecasting method to the seasonally adjusted data (aka STL decomp + non-seasonal ETS model applied), then reseasonalizes the last year of the seasonal component.